# Keyboard And Mouse Won't Work, but works on BIOS

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, mouse

today i'm using my laptop because i have problem with my mouse and keyboard on the other pc. I cant access to device manager because of it, even on safe mode, still don't work. This problem occur after i use a software to automatically update drivers. Any suggestions ?

here some of my specs, i can't completely list all because of the problem
Windows XP SP3 Black Edition
Ram 1 GB
DirectX 9
Hard Drive About1 170 GB

Comment: Did you try booting into safe mode? Hold down **Ctrl** while booting to get to the menu.

Comment: Yeah, I try booting into safe mode, but the mouse just infinitely blinking its red light, the keyboard also blink a light whenever i click a button. Still they didn't work

Comment: Everything does point towards your bad choice of driver updates, but to avoid jumping to conclusions, did you try a different mouse or keyboard on different USB ports?

Comment: Attach _USB_ keyboard and mouse if current ones are _PS2_ or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, I also try it, But nothing works.

Comment: @JosefZ I Have no PS2 mouse just USB

Comment: Do you have [remote desktop](http://windowsitpro.com/article/remote-computing/how-do-i-enable-remote-desktop-in-windows-xp--20601) enabled and configured? Connect from your laptop to [Restore Windows XP to a Previous State](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457025.aspx) before drivers update.

Comment: Can you try booting from the Windows installation DVD and activate a system restore point? If there isn't a convenient one, you should be able to remove all driver settings from there (on mobile, so hard to write right now).

Comment: @mario yeah I'll try that...

Comment: @JosefZ I don't know That

Answer (score 1):

Since changing Keyboard and Mouse doesn't seem to work.
You could try this procedure to return to a state before you installed the driver update software:

- Start the computer and then press the F8 key when Windows begins to start. The Windows Advanced Options menu appears.
- Use the ARROW keys to select Last Known Good Configuration (your most recent settings that worked), and then press ENTER.
- If a boot menu appears, use the ARROW keys to select Microsoft Windows XP, and then press ENTER. Windows XP restores the computer to the most recent restore point.

more info at : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457025.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. It doesn't work if the keyboard doesn't work as it says in the question.

Comment: Well he said his keyboard and mouse does not work on a booted windows but on bios it does, since he can boot in safe mode that says he can use his keyboard before boot, he might as well try to launch the restore mode.