# New computer does not recognize keyboard/mouse past BIOS

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

I recently built a new PC and moved my old hard drives into the new computer without reinstalling Windows using sysprep. When I first set up windows the keyboard and mouse worked correctly, however when I installed the USB3.0 drivers that came on my motherboard's setup disk, my USB mouse and keyboard ceased to work and have not worked since (I also got a message warning me that the drivers did not install correctly). I can access the BIOS, the boot menu, and boot Windows in safe mode, however once Windows starts my keyboard's and mouse's lights turn off and they do not work. Additionally, they do not work in safe mode either. I should mention that I ONLY have USB3.0 ports, and I have tried all the ports. My USB ports haven't gone bad because I can boot from my USB stick still. However, using both my Windows installation USB and my Ubuntu USB the mouse and keyboard still do not work. I am interested in how installing a Windows driver prevents the mouse from working in Ubuntu! I have PS/2 to USB in the mail, but it would be nice if there was an easier way to fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard And Mouse Won't Work, but works on BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1089413/keyboard-and-mouse-wont-work-but-works-on-bios)

Answer (score 0):

You basically have explained the problem. Your USB drivers are not working because the drivers did not install, and as such your USB ports can't function.

Using the PS/2 to USB will allow you to fix the issue, but given that the USB3.0 ports do not work in Ubuntu either makes me wonder if you maybe have set the USB ports to a 2.0 state through the BIOS (legacy USB support) while using drivers specifically for USB 3.0 ports.

Your Ubuntu would then run into the same problem. It has drivers for 3.0 USB support, but the BIOS is not supplying them.

With the PS/2 to USB, you will be able to uninstall the drivers in windows and let windows install the old drivers which will likely make it work as USB 2.0 ports.

Comment: I had tried with legacy USB support both enabled and disabled with no difference. I cannot say why Ubuntu did not work, as it does work now. Additionally, I plugged in the USB2.0 ports from my old PC and Windows still refused to recognize the keyboard or mouse. I tried deleting the driver files using Ubuntu, but unsurprisingly this had no effect.